# Syntax Error 42561. ERROR: syntax error at or near ";"

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I've been receiving a syntax error on my create function statement and no matter what I try, I can't seem to find why it shows this error.

Here is the part of the code that shows the error:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.fnc_Name(
    param character varying)
 RETURNS json
AS $BODY$

Declare
--VAriables
   _result varchar;
   _error_code varchar;
   _error_msg varchar;

BEGIN

--redacted code

    BEGIN
    exception when OTHERS then
        _result = -1;
        _error_code = 130;
            GET STACKED DIAGNOSTICS _error_msg = MESSAGE_TEXT;    
            SELECT json_build_object('status', _status , 'error_code' , 
    _error_code, 'error_message', _error_msg) INTO _result;
    return _result;
    END;

END; --Error shows at this ; 
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: It is work on my PostgreSQL 10 from pgsql. Maybe you postgresql client has some problems or maybe you some too old version of Postgres.

Comment: I'm running pgsql 9.5.13, can't upgrade it at the moment.

Comment: 9.5 should be ok. It is not too old. Try to paste your function via psql

Comment: You are probably using a client that gets confused. Use something different, ideally `psql`.

Comment: Which SQL client are you using? It probably doesn't know anything about dollar quoting

Comment: Currently using PGAdmin 4 for windows. will try on other clients to see if there is any difference